# Django 1.5 giving 404s for pk > 999

Tags: python, django

**What I'm trying to do**
I have a simple view that takes a pk as an argument and performs an action. This worked fine until the pks were greater than 999. Now they return 404s. I'm trying to fix this.

**What I've tried**
My view looks like this:

```
def request_publication(request, pk):
    ...
    article = News.all_news.get(pk=pk) # all_news is a manager including unpublished articles
    article.status = article.HIDDEN_STATUS
    article.save()
    ...
```

And the url regex is like this:

```
regex=r'^request-publication/(?P<pk>\d+)/',
```

I've also tried:

```
regex=r'^request-publication/(?P<pk>\d{4})/',
```

which makes it fail on pks < 1000 as expected, but still doesn't work for pk>999.

The full `urls.py` is:

```
# core Django imports
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# local imports
from .models import News, Category, Attachment
from .views import (
    NewsHomeView,
    CategoryHomeView,
    NewsDetailView,
    NewsYearArchiveView,
    NewsMonthArchiveView,
    NewsDayArchiveView,
    NewsListView,
    NewsCreateView,
    NewsUpdateView,
    publish,
    request_publication,
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        regex = r'^$',
        view = NewsHomeView.as_view(),
        name = "news_home",
        ),
    url(
        regex = r'^add/$',
        view = NewsCreateView.as_view(),
        name = 'news_add',
    ),
    url(
        regex = r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        view = NewsUpdateView.as_view(),
        name = 'news_update',
    ),
    url(
        regex = r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        view = CategoryHomeView.as_view(),
        name = 'category_detail',
        ),
    url(
        regex = r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        view = NewsListView.as_view(),
        name = 'news_tag_list',
    ),
    url(
        regex = r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/$',
        view = NewsYearArchiveView.as_view(),
        name = "year_archive",
        ),
    url(
        regex = r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$',
        view = NewsMonthArchiveView.as_view(),
        name = "month_archive",
        ),
    url(
        regex = r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$',
        view = NewsDayArchiveView.as_view(),
        name = "day_archive",
        ),
    url(
        regex = r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        view = NewsDetailView.as_view(),
        name = "article",
        ),
    url(
        regex = r'^publish/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        view = publish,
        name = 'publish',
    ),
    url(
        regex = r'^request-publication/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        view = request_publication,
        name = 'request_publication',
    ),
)
```

Calling `News.all_news.get(pk=1000)` from a shell works perfectly, with `all_news` being an alias for the standard Django `objects` manager because I've overridden `objects` with a custom manager.

**What I'm expecting**
I can't see any reason why this would fail. I'm expecting the view to return successfully.

**What is actually happening**
The standard 404 page.

**Restrictions**
I can't upgrade to a more recent Django for this alone due to corporate restrictions.

**Question(s)**
Has anyone else experienced this and how did you fix it?

Comment: You're sure that you have corresponding `News` models in the database? What happens if you open a shell and request the same `pk` of the model?

Comment: Yes, I should have added that calling News.all_news.get(pk=1000) in a shell works fine! I'll edit.

Comment: @cms_mgr  wait, it should be `News.objects.get(pk=1000)` or do you have a custom `ModelManager` ?

Comment: Are there other URL regular expressions that might apply as well?

Comment: @levi Yes, see the comment in the code block.

Comment: @cms_mgr in your view when u print `pk`, you get the correct `int` ?

Comment: @levi that's hard for me to test as this is only showing up on live (test and staging don't have > 999 articles in their databases). I can say that the view still works perfectly for the first 999 articles.

Comment: The problem in the view. We can not judge without seeing the code.

Comment: Please also show the full urls.py.

Comment: @Othman the view code is there. The only bits missing are checking whether the user is authenticated and redirecting to the original article upon completion. Both of these work fine for pk < 1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The request to `request-publication/1000` is being caught by the `year-archive` view, since it matches the pattern `r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/$` when a three-digit pk would not.

You therefore get a 404 as you have no items published in the year 1000 matching the slug "requests-publication".

Comment: Nice catch yes, its your [-\w] specifically that matches "request-publication"